# How to retroactively chain inclusion of multiple header files in php

Tags: php, apache, header, include, require

This is what I'm trying to figure out.

[image: Why does chain include or require work up one level, but not two?]

In other words if I write the following at the very beginning of index.php:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

That works. ...but, if I go one step further and ALSO write the following at the beginning of header.php:

```
<?php include("html_header.php"); ?>
```

What happens then is the application only renders up to header.php. Why does it not render html_header.php?

Hope this is clear enough for future references. I would also like to know if there is anyway of achieving this type of chaining especially when relating to the headers. Thank you.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work like this. Do you have any error message? Or what's the output?

Comment: No errors. nothing. Not even the log files. No warnings either. It just doesn't render. index.php goes through no problem. The other 2 do not. So what I get as output is a page with all the content but no css or javascript.

Comment: CORRECTION EDIT: header.php goes through. However, in header.php the inclusion for html_header.php DOES NOT work. So inclusion works up to 1 level but after that, no go.

Comment: How do you know that html_header isn't loaded? What is supposed to be the output? Can we see the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! I feel like such an idiot. First of all, I was missing a quotation mark(?). In header.php I had `<php require("html_header.php") ?>` which is why it wasn't working but even if that hadn't worked, all I really needed to do was place both the include of header.php and the require of html_header.php together in index.php instead of separate on each file. Why I tried to do it the other way, I have no idea, but this was a real brain fart. Thanks anyways @David Kuna.